# Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

In sql query editor I have the following commands:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tUserPreference ON

BULK INSERT tUserPreference
FROM 'D:\test.txt'
WITH
(   KEEPIDENTITY,
    BATCHSIZE = 2,
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' ,
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    KEEPNULLS
    );
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tUserPreference OFF
GO
```

content of the test.txt:

```
"UserPreferenceId","UserId","UserPreferenceValue","UserPreferenceTypeId"
7858,1194,"FSP,FRB,FWF,FBVS,FRRC",15
7859,1194,"FIRM",21
7860,1194,"009,61,114,142,174,233,262,286,303,325,369,389,411,671,690,735,938,943,977,105,200",11
7861,1194,"B545,B441",12
7862,1194,"{"FIRM":{"accountType":"Firm","timeInForce":"DAY","routing":"DNR","isAllOrNone":false}}",2
```

But when I execute these command I see following result:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 4 (UserPreferenceTypeId).
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tUserPreference_UserPreferenceId'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tUserPreference'. The duplicate key value is (7859).
The statement has been terminated.
```

and only 1 row inserts (`7861,1194,"B545,B441",12`)

table create script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tUserPreference](
    [UserPreferenceId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,
    [UserPreferenceValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [UserPreferenceTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tUserPreference_UserPreferenceId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
....
```

How to insert using bulk Insert properly?

Comment: You need a format file if you want SQL Server to assign identity values during `BULK INSERT`. [See the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BULK INSERT with identity (auto-increment) column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851065/bulk-insert-with-identity-auto-increment-column)

Comment: @Chris Pickford i need insert identity field

Comment: @gstackoverflow See the answers to the linked question; you can either insert to a temporary staging table, then upsert from there, or create a format file.

Comment: @Chris Pickford I cannot understand how to create format file. I use commas as delimeter and commas inside field

Comment: If you can't follow the documentation linked by Aaron above or the question linked, then no answer here will help you either!

Comment: @DavidG should I generate this format file or should I write it manually ?

Comment: Use the `keepidentity` argument. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx. However, you may want to consider a different approach, e.g. bulk inserting into a staging table and then merging the results.

Comment: @Yobik topic updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE tUserPreference1 (DataField VARCHAR(1000))

BULK INSERT tUserPreference1
FROM 'C:\Shared\text.txt'
WITH
(   
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    KEEPNULLS
    );

select  SUBSTRING(DataField,1,4)    AS UserPreferenceId
        ,SUBSTRING(DataField,6,4)   AS UserId
        ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(DataField),1,CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(DataField))-1))   UserPreferenceTypeId
        ,DataField
INTO    tUserPreference2
from    tUserPreference1

SELECT  *
        ,SUBSTRING(DataField,11,LEN(DataField)-(11+LEN(UserPreferenceTypeId))) AS UserPreferenceValue
FROM    tUserPreference2
```

Comment: actual file is too long

Comment: Do we at least know the lengths data can have? i.e. isUserPreferenceId always 4 digits? UserId 4 digits? and UserpreferenceTypeId 1 or 2 digits?

Comment: Check the edited answer. From this you can get a table with the require data. From there insert it into the table you want.

Comment: Invalid column name 'DataField'.

Comment: Edited. Check now.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'DataField'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'DataField'.

Comment: I use sql server 2008

Comment: SQL Server version doesn't have an issue with the code. Did you copy paste the edited code as is? Can put the code you are running?