# TSQL BULK INSERT with auto incremented key from .txt file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcUmG.png)

This is to insert into an already created table:

```
 CREATE TABLE SERIES(

SERIES_NAME VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL UNIQUE, --MADE VARCHAR(225) & UNIQUE FOR FK REFERENCE
ONGOING_SERIES BIT, --BOOL FOR T/F IF SERIES IS COMPLETED OR NOT
RUN_START DATE, 
RUN_END DATE,
MAIN_CHARACTER VARCHAR(20),
PUBLISHER VARCHAR(12),
S_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
CONSTRAINT chk_DATES CHECK (RUN_START < RUN_END)
)
```

and the text file is organized as:

> GREEN LANTERN,0,2005-07-01,2011-09-01,HAL JORDAN,DC
>
> SPIDERMAN,0,2005-07-01,2011-09-01,PETER PARKER,MARVEL

I have already tried adding commas to the end of each line in .txt file
I have also tried adding ,' ' to the end of each line.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem or question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BULK INSERT with identity (auto-increment) column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851065/bulk-insert-with-identity-auto-increment-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the KEEPIDENTITY prevents the bulk insert from taken place. Removing the statement however won't resolve the problem.

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 7 (S_ID).
```

The bulk insert expects to update all the columns. Another way of solving this issue is adding a format file for the text file, see [MS Docs - Use a Format File to Bulk Import Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server)

You can create a format file for your text file with the following command.

```
bcp yourdatabase.dbo.series format nul -c -f D:\test.fmt -t, -T
```

Remove the last row, update the number of columns, and replace the last comma with the row terminator. The result will look like as shown below.

```
13.0
6
1       SQLCHAR             0       255     ","      1     SERIES_NAME                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       1       ","      2     ONGOING_SERIES                   ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       11      ","      3     RUN_START                        ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       11      ","      4     RUN_END                          ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       510     ","      5     MAIN_CHARACTER                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       510     "\r\n"   6     PUBLISHER                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `KEEPIDENTIY` from your BULK INSERT, since that specifies that you want to use the values in the source text file as your IDENTITY.

If this still fails, try adding a VIEW on the table that excludes the IDENTITY field, and INSERT into that instead, e.g.:

```
CREATE VIEW SeriesBulkInsertTarget 
AS
    SELECT Series_Name,
        Ongoing_Series,
        Run_Start,
        Run_End,
        Main_Character,
        Publisher
    FROM SERIES
```